# In Android Studio, how do I change the Kotlin naming conventions?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, lint

Android Studio just updated its Kotlin plugin, and suddenly my code is polluted with warnings about the naming conventions. Apparently Google and/or JetBrains think everyone ought to use CamelCase, but (a) I prefer snake_case (use of underscores), (b) nearly every line of my sources now has a lint complaint, making it hard to separate the wheat from the chaff, and (c) I don't have time to rewrite all my code just to pander to other people's aesthetic sense.

How do I convince AS to be a Philistine like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu, select File, then Settings. In the leftmost panel of the window that now appears, select **Editor**, then Inspections. In the *next* leftmost panel that now appears, find **Kotlin**, unfold it by clicking on the triangle, then find **Naming conventions**, and unfold that. You now have two options.

If you want AS to disregard Kotlin naming conventions, you can simply uncheck its box, and the boxes below it.

However, you can actually use this to convince AS to convert to snake_case instead of CamelCase, or any other aesthetic, as opposed to Google's and/or JetBrains'. If you click on, for instance, "Class naming convention," you will see on the right a text box labeled "Pattern:". It will probably contain `[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]*`. Add an underscore in a strategic location according to regex rules, for instance, `[A-Z][_A-Za-z\d]*`. Do this for each of the identifier types whose naming convention you'd like to change, and you're good to go.